# 'Magnet' and 'Delete' buttons won't show up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I own a 1.8 server running Bukkit. I have Essentials and bPermissions installed.

Client-side, I have NEI installed and I can't seem to get the `Magnet` and `Delete` buttons to show up. Every other button shows up. I go to cheat mode, I override the global settings, and they still don't show up. It works fine on my 1.7.10 singleplayer world.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Do you have access to the server and is it running NEI? If so its the Server configs you will have to change/update, not your local ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnet and delete item buttons will show up in multiplayer servers if NEI is installed on both the client side and the server side, with the NEI config allowing the use of these features.